# python - is there a function to return the maximum integer but not float from a list

Tags: python, integer

I am trying to code a function that will accept a list and then return the length of the list times the largest integer (not float) in the list, if the list does not contain an integer, it needs to return an empty string.

I had been trying to use the max function but I cannot work out how to only call for the largest integer not float, or is there a way to sort the list first to only look at integers?

Comment: Where is your attempt? Where is the example? Do you consider `3.0` an integer? Why an empty string, that just seems very odd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want to do, this should work:

```
def return_max_times_len(l):
    lst_int = [i for i in l if isinstance(i, int)]
    if len(lst_int) > 0:
        return len(l) * max(lst_int)
    return ""
```

Comment: Hi this has worked thank you, could you help explain the second line is it for integer in list if it is an integer and the length of the list is greater than 0 than it does the calculation, just want to be sure what isinstance does. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: `isinstance(i, int)` checks if `i` is an instance of `int`. So this line creates a list containing only the integers of the original list; if the list is empty, `len(lst_int)` is equal zero and the empty string is returned. Otherwise, the maximum element of the list is multiplied with the length of the original list.

Answer (score 0):

you might be able to use an if statement to check if the number is an interger

Comment: An example code here would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

as a one liner you could do:

```
max([i for i in data if type(i) == int])
```

that will throw a error, if there is no int, so you would have to catch that.

if you need the empty string, you could do

```
int_data = [i for i in data if type(i) == int]
if len(int_data) == 0:
    print("")
else:
    print(len(data) * max(int_data))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you :)

```
def func(lst):
    length = 0
    flag = False
    eps = 0.000001
    max = -inf
    for elem in lst:
        length += 1
        if (abs(elem - int(elem)) <= eps) and (elem >= max):
            max = elem
            flag = True
    if flag:
        print(max * length)
    else:
        print("")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following construction to get the frequency of integers contained in your list

```
from collections import defaultdict
counts = defaultdict(int)
numbers = [3, 4.5, 6, 3.2, 7.8, 6]

for num in numbers:
    if type(num) == int:
        counts[num] += 1

largest_integer = max(counts)
frequency = counts[largest_integer]
```

The dict 'counts' will contain the frequency of integers included in the list 'numbers'. The structure of 'counts' is the following:

```
{integer1: times_met, integer2: times_met...}
```

Answer (score -1):

here it is.

```
def lili(list: list) -> int:
    if all(isinstance(item, int) for item in list):  # Check if all element in the list are integer
        return len(list) * max(list)
    return None


print(lili([2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))
```

If you don't understand something please hit me up, I will explain you more clearly.